# update UITableview cell with UITextfield text change

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, textfield

Let say, I have a UITableView with a cell having two textfields and 1 label. As label shows the sum of textfield's numbers, label updates whenever user edit textField. The problem, I am facing is, whenever user types in textField, I called tableView.reloadData() function to update label with latest sum and this results in resigning textField and keyboard gets hide. What I want is to update label with open keyboard. How can I achieve this? Following is the sample code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.textField1.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.textField2.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.textField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textField1Edited), for: .editingChanged)
    cell.textField2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textField2Edited), for: .editingChanged)
    cell.sumLabel.text = "\(textField1Values[indexPath.row]+textField2Values[indexPath.row])"
return cell
}
@objc func textField1Edited(sender: UITextField!) {
    textField1Values[sender.tag] = sender.text
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
@objc func textField2Edited(sender: UITextField!) {
    textField2Values[sender.tag] = sender.text
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your TableViewCell should implement [UITextFieldDelegate.shouldChangeCharacters(in:replacementString:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield).  Return true from this function and update your label based on the value of textField.text with the replaced proposed replacementString.

**EDIT:** Here is a playground showing hwo to use the delegate to update a label as you type:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class V: UIViewController {
    let label = UILabel()
    let textField = UITextField()
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textField)
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        label.text = " "
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        textField.placeholder = "Enter a number"
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    }
}

extension V: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = textField.text else {
            return true
        }
        let proposed = text.replacingCharacters(in: Range(range, in: text)!, with: string)
        label.text = "You Entered \(proposed)"
        return true
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = V()
```

Comment: can you please share some demo code? it would be very helpful

Comment: @danishnaeem , Can you post your code, I can modify that and provide. jzk

Comment: Don't do it in the view controller.  You need to do it in the tableViewCell.  Otherwise reload is going to recycle the cell and its going to resign first responder.